# Helm rollback hook from current release

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Let's say I have two versions of chart *Foo* - v1 and v2. I had installed v1 (as revision 1) then upgraded to v2 (revision 2).

Now I'd like to rollback to first revision (`helm rollback Foo 1`). Is there any way to run job **defined in v2** at some point of rollback **after** v1 resources are restored.

It must perform some actions on v1 resources because backwards incompatible changes made in v2.

I'd assume that pre-rollback hook defined in v2 should do the job. Unfortunetly chart lifecycle documentation is a bit confusing for me.

---

I tried to use

```yaml
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": post-rollback
```

as suggested in the answers. Unfortunately when I do rollback from v2 to v1 then v1's version of pre/post rollback job is executed. I need to execute job defined in v2 chart.

Comment: Based on your edits, it sounds like you're interested in a `pre-rollback` hook, since you're rolling back `v2` and want the job defined there to run? I'm not sure you could accomplish getting the `v2` job to run only after the roll back to `v1` is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible, Helm always uses hooks from target release, in this case from v1.

Answer (score 1):

The following documentation and examples should clear up your confusion -

https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/#the-available-hooks

https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/#writing-a-hook

tldr

Add the following to the job you want to execute.

```
annotations:
  "helm.sh/hook": post-rollback
```

Answer (score 0):

`pre-rollback` is executed before any resources are created. Your desire state is to have that job to run on already created resources so you have to use `post-rollback` hook as described in the documentation:

> post-rollback Executes on a rollback request after all resources have been modified